# Vb from Access importing data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I have the following code in visual basic which currently allows data from one table to populate a form. I need to be able to select data from another table and add that data onto the same form relevant to the student number primary key.

```vb
Private Sub ButSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButSearch.Click
        If TxtSearchFirstname.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields..", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            Call Connection()
            Try
                Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE FirstName='" & TxtSearchFirstname.Text & "' "
                Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)
                sqlCom.Connection = conn
                Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()
                Dim Test As String : Test = sqlRead.Read()
                TxtFirstname.Text = sqlRead.GetString(0)
                TxtLastname.Text = sqlRead.GetString(1)
                TxtYear.Text = sqlRead.GetString(2)
                TxtGender.Text = sqlRead.GetString(3)
                TxtTarget.Text = sqlRead.GetString(4)
                TxtStudentNumber.Text = sqlRead.GetValue(5)


            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Database..", "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End If
```

Comment: You've told us what you want but not what you've tried in order to achieve it. Have you tried using different SQL or writing a second subroutine which gets information from the other table? You'll need to show us your attempt and explain what's going wrong (e.g. error, incorrect output, computer exploded) before this becomes a singularly answerable question.

Comment: You might want to be aware that your code is currently open to SQL Injection.  This  may not be the end of the world, if it's only being used by yourself, but certainly something you should be aware of if anyone else is touching the application.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `INNER JOIN` sentence to grab data from multiples tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A join is needed here. You could use something like this:

```
 Dim sql As String = "SELECT S.*, OT.Whatever FROM Students S LEFT JOIN OtherTable OT ON S.SomeColumn = OT.SomeColumn WHERE FirstName=@FirstName"
 Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)
 sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtSearchFirstname.Text
```